# C programming get Information from the user

Tags: c, string

This my first using C
 I need to ask user some information to enter

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int age;
    int i;
    char last_name[20];
    char first_name[20];
    double wight;
    char gender[1];


    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Enter your last name: ");
    fgets(last_name, 18, stdin);
        i = strlen(last_name)-1;
        if( last_name[ i ] == '\n')
            last_name[i] = '\0';

    printf("Enter your first name: ");
    fgets(first_name, 18, stdin);
            i = strlen(first_name)-1;
            if( first_name[ i ] == '\n')
                first_name[i] = '\0';

    printf("Enter your wight: ");
    scanf("%lf", &wight);
    printf("Enter your gender m/f: ");
    gets(gender);

    printf("You entered %s successfully\n ", first_name);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I run the program 
 **Enter your age: 23
 Enter your last name: Enter your first name:**

I did not give me chance to enter the last name
 it jump to next line

I am using eclipse ide

Comment: why not scanf("%s",first_name) and so on?

Answer (score 0):

The newline char at the end of input `age` is getting picket by `fgets()`
You need to flush this newline char in the stdin buffer to make sure it is not picked by `fgets()` .

Use

```
scanf("%d%*c",&age);
```

Comment: using `fflush()` on input streams is not recommended, as the does not specify behaviour for input streams. so `fflush(stdin)` shoul never been used. [Read here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

Comment: @akhilesh1988 Yes that's the reason I gave a good alternative to it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int age;
    int i;
    char last_name[20];
    char first_name[20];
    double wight;
    char gender[1];


    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Enter your last name: ");
    __fpurge ( stdin );
    fgets(last_name, 18, stdin);
        i = strlen(last_name)-1;
        if( last_name[ i ] == '\n')
            last_name[i] = '\0';

    printf("Enter your first name: ");
    fgets(first_name, 18, stdin);
            i = strlen(first_name)-1;
            if( first_name[ i ] == '\n')
                first_name[i] = '\0';

    printf("Enter your wight: ");
    scanf("%lf", &wight);
    printf("Enter your gender m/f: ");
    __fpurge ( stdin );
    gets(gender);

    printf("You entered %s successfully\n ", first_name);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I run the program Enter your age: 23 Enter your last name: Enter your first name:

This happens after the first `scanf` in your code:

```
scanf("%d", &age);
```

When you take `age` as input a newline is still trailing in the input stream, you need to clear it before taking next input:

```
scanf("%d", &age);
while(getchar() != '\n'); //eat up trailing newline
fgets(last_name, 18, stdin);
```

Here is your corrected program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int age;
    int i;
    char last_name[20];
    char first_name[20];
    double wight;
    char gender[1];


    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Enter your last name: ");
    while(getchar() != '\n'); //eat up trailing newline
    fgets(last_name, 18, stdin);
        i = strlen(last_name)-1;
        if( last_name[ i ] == '\n')
            last_name[i] = '\0';

    printf("Enter your first name: ");
    fgets(first_name, 18, stdin);
            i = strlen(first_name)-1;
            if( first_name[ i ] == '\n')
                first_name[i] = '\0';

    printf("Enter your wight: ");
    scanf("%lf", &wight);
    printf("Enter your gender m/f: ");
    while(getchar() != '\n'); //eat up trailing newline
    gets(gender);

    printf("You entered %s successfully\n ", first_name);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter your age: 25
Enter your last name: last_Name
Enter your first name: First_Name
Enter your wight: 70
Enter your gender m/f: M
You entered First_Name successfully
```